# Adding all columns together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function subTotals() {
    var otTableTotal = 0;
    var sTableTotal = 1;
    var r = parseFloat($('#rate').val());
    $('.ot').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).data('mins') !== undefined) {
            otTableTotal += $(this).data('mins');
        }
    });
    $('#ot_subtotal').html(convertToHours(otTableTotal));
    $('#otE_subtotal').text((((otTableTotal / 60) * r) * 1.5).toFixed(2));
    var hoursTableTotal = 0;
    $('.hours').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).data('mins') !== undefined) {
            hoursTableTotal += $(this).data('mins');
        }
    });
      $('.sick').each(function(index) {
            sTableTotal += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#s_subtotal',this).html(sTableTotal);
    $('#hours_subtotal').html(convertToHours(hoursTableTotal));
    //$('#tE_subtotal').text(((hoursTableTotal / 60) * r).toFixed(2));
    $('#tE_subtotal').text(((((hoursTableTotal / 60) * r)) +(((otTableTotal / 60) * r) * 1.5)).toFixed(2));
    $('#rE_subtotal').text((((hoursTableTotal / 60) * r)).toFixed(2));

}
```

I am having trouble getting my sick column to add up and display where totals is. (The first 2 zeroes are for Hours and Overtime Hours which I have working.) I just can't get this darned sick thing to work.

[image: Table]

Comment: Reading your text I thought you was angry, later I saw the *sick* column in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the context (`this`) here:

```
$('#s_subtotal',this).html(sTableTotal);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That still didn't fix the issue unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which shows your problem (and your html)?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. I had to add it to the event handler for my input box. (Also, I did need to remove the "this" as you said.) Thank you!